# Do not see MySQL in windows 10 services.msc

Tags: mysql

I have installed MySql in my windows 10 machine, I see an error sayng unable to connect to localhost:3306. When i go to the servies i do not see MySQL in the list, Also i do not see bin folder in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder for the ini

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0
```

The Bin folder

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
```

The service is call

```
MySQL80
```

for teh other versions is has it own folders and service name such as MYSQL57 and so on.

Also look in the error log there you find the problem.

If you can not find the error.log look in the my.ini file for teh location.

Comment: Just elaborating on your answer and clarifying @peter's question: the `MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE` folder is for Workbench specifically (it's the user interface).  The `MySQL Server 8.0` directory is for actual MySQL, which will run the database.

Comment: i elaborated on the prior version. I was blinded by the menbtion of workbench 8, which don't wiork well with earlier versions. but thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i do not see bin folder in that location. i have have updated my initial post with the screenshot of it.

Comment: Workbench is a gui for mysql it is not the database, itself that has to be installed separately